# Forced to retain a new instance of a class and therefore leaking memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, initialization

I have created a property list, that when unarchived, initialises an array of instances of a class called 'SelectableObject'. The SelectableObject class does not contain an init method, it is just a container for some instance variables, and of course conforms to NSCoding.

When a SelectableObject is chosen, I initialise a new instance of a subclass of SelectableObject, depending on which object was selected. Call this 'AnimalObject'.

I have written a custom initialiser for AnimalObject, which takes a SelectableObject as an argument, to get the SelectableObject's values, and then adds some of its own value. So the method looks like this:

```
- (AnimalObject *)initWithObject:(SelectableObject *)selectedObject
```

And I call it from the selection screen like this:

```
AnimalObject *animal = [[AnimalObject alloc] initWithObject:self.selectedObject];
```

where self.selectedObject is the object selected from the selection screen.

Now, in the initialiser for the AnimalObject, I set the initial values, then just before returning it, call

```
[self saveToFile];
```

to save the new object to file. So having initialised it in the selection screen, I should be able to release it straight away right?

However, if I try to release it, i.e

```
    AnimalObject *animal = [[AnimalObject alloc] initWithObject:self.selectedObject];
[animal release];
```

I get a crash.

If I don't release it, I get a warning that all the iVars initialised in the AnimalObject initialiser are leaking memory.

I've tried creating an AnimalObject property in the selectionScreen and assigning the new object to it before releasing, but this still crashes, i.e.

```
self.newAnimal = animal;
[animal release];
```

I'm wondering if from my description above, I'm doing something very wrong? Like saving a class from within its initialiser. Or passing a parent class as an object to an initialiser of a subclass... I'm not really sure why I can't release the instance of the object I created.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT Ok, here's my code:

The selectable Object class:

```
#define kObjectNumberKey            @"ObjectNumber"
#define kObjectTypeKey              @"Type"
#define kObjectNameKey              @"Name"
#define kObjectThumbKey             @"Thumb"
#define kObjectMainKey              @"Main"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SelectableObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    int         number;
    NSString    *type;
    NSString    *name;
    NSString    *thumbString;
    NSString    *mainString;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thumbString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mainString;

@end

#import "SelectableObject.h"

@implementation SelectableObject

@synthesize number;
@synthesize type;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize thumbString;
@synthesize mainString;


- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Selectable Object DEALLOC");
    [name release];
    [type release];
    [thumbString release];
    [mainString release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSCoding

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeInt:self.number forKey:kObjectNumberKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.type forKey:kObjectTypeKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:kObjectNameKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.thumbString forKey:kObjectThumbKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.mainString forKey:kObjectMainKey];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.number = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:kObjectNumberKey];
        self.type = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kObjectTypeKey];
        self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kObjectNameKey];
        self.thumbString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kObjectThumbKey];
        self.mainString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kObjectMainKey];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The code in another VC to create a new Animal object with the details of the SelectedObject:

```
- (void)createNewAnimal {
    self.selectedObject.name = self.nameField.text;

    Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithObject:self.selectedObject];
//  [animal release]; (causes it to crash)

    // Initialise the new Root Controller and load with selected object
}
```

And in the Animal class:

```
- (Animal *)initWithObject:(SelectableObject *)selectedObject {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //Initialise all the values
        dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        dateLastUsed = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        name = selectedObject.name;
        thumbString = selectedObject.thumbString;
        mainString = selectedObject.mainString;
    }   
    [self saveToFile];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with your description. It would help to see the code in `initWithObject:` and the declarations for your properties in `AnimalObject`. Also, the code in your `dealloc` method might provide clues too.

Comment: Does `selectedObject` get retained?  It may not be `animalObject` that is the problem, but what you're passing in as a init parameter.

Comment: I think you're right Stephen. selectedObject is retained, and if I comment its release out in the dealloc method, the program runs fine! Apart from the fact it isn't released of course. So I shouldn't pass a retained parent object as a parameter of an initialiser of its subclass? Hmmm - how can I pass the details of the selected object and still release the selectedObject?

Comment: If you can, please create a minimal test case that we can look at and ideally run to get the same result you're seeing. That makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot. At the very least, I think we'd need to see the init and dealloc methods for these classes to determine what's up.

Comment: Ok - I've added my code, with fluff removed... It must be something to do with how I pass the selectedObject to the intialiser, since removing its release call from the dealloc method of the class that calls it avoids the crash. Should I initialise a new SelectableObject with the same parameters as the one that was selected and pass that as the argument instead perhaps? Seems a bit long winded...

Comment: What is the call stack when it crashes?

Comment: Doesn't manage a call stack unfortunately, but with zombies on I get *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x739c2d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initWithObject is perhaps a bit suspect. Does Animal's dealloc release `name`, `thumbString`, and `mainString`? If so, then they are being released twice.

```
- (Animal *)initWithObject:(SelectableObject *)selectedObject {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //Initialise all the values
        dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        dateLastUsed = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        name = [selectedObject.name retain]; // Added retain
        thumbString = [selectedObject.thumbString retain]; // Added retain
        mainString = [selectedObject.mainString retain]; // Added retain
    }   
    [self saveToFile];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: No, Animal's dealloc only releases the iVars it creates, i.e. dateCreated and dateLastUsed. It calls [super dealloc] where the name, thumbString and mainString are released.

Comment: If Animal does NOT retain/release those strings then as soon as your SelectedObject that was used as a parameter to `initWithObject:` is deallocated the pointers in Animal become junk and accessing them is undefined behavior. That is, unless you have a guarantee that the SelectedObject will outlive Animal you MUST retain or copy those properties.

Comment: Of course! I never thought about it like that, but you're absolutely right. I thought that initialising them to the Animal object's iVars would be enough to retain them, but since I'm not using accessor methods (being in the init method), I guess this isn't the case. Adding the retains fixed it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

How does the dealloc() method of Animal look? Are you releasing name, thumbString and mainString in there? If yes, then there is your crash.

Due to the fastest gun in the west problem the answer was already provided by @imaginaryboy. Since mainString and thumbString gets released in the super class it will crash. Just add a retain in the init method and you should be all set.

*Note:* `NSString`'s should use copy instead of retain.

Comment: Nope, not releasing them there. I think it's the selectableObject that I pass as an argument. It seems that it's released in the intialiser somehow, so that when it's released in the superclass, it crashes...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the case. You should only release when you have retained and in this case you have not retained the strings in question, just assigned them. Try @imaginaryboy's code and I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Great - thanks! Fastest gun or not, really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot in the dark but did you try

```
  AnimalObject *animal = [[[AnimalObject alloc] initWithObject:self.selectedObject] autorelease];
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it still crashes. I'm pretty sure it's to do with the release of the selectedObject instance variable...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem here but until now I have only seen init methods witch return an id type, like

```
- (id)init
```

I didn't try to return an other type than id up to now.

Comment: I think this is important when you're subclassing, so that subclasses can call self = [super init], but since I'm not, I just used the actual return type. Probably better practice to stick to id though, thanks for the tip!